# Saving/Loading content from/to several comboboxes

Tags: java, swing

I have several comboboxes which contains some Pc components. Each Combobox represents some specific component (cpu, gpu, ram etc.), each component is determined by severel atributes (prize, name, etc.),only name(of the component) is visible in each combobox.
I need to Serialize selected content and save it to external .bin file , from this file I should be able to load previous choices and set them as selected. As for saving: I take selected Strings from each Combobox, I add them to ArrayList and serialize it. The saving works (but is useless obviously) but I can't find out how to load values from the file.

Comment: Code samples and/or example runnable class would work wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the serialized object(s) from your file(s) using an ObjectInputStream.  See the below example.

```
    InputStream fileIS = null;
    InputStream bufferedIS = null;
    ObjectInput objectIS = null;
    try{
        fileIS = new FileInputStream("yourFileName.txt");
        bufferedIS = new BufferedInputStream(fileIS);
        objectIS = new ObjectInputStream(bufferedIS);
        try {
            // cast to List<String> or String or whatever object you are working with
            Object yourObjectOrObjects = objectIS.readObject();
            // do something with your object or objects

        }
        finally{
            objectIS.close();
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To load values of the file, you will need to deserialize your array using ObjectInputStream. After that, just set the text of your combo boxes

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("save.bin"); //Your file name
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();

    ois.close();
    fis.close();
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex); //Handle your exception however you want to
}
```

Modify that code to read in to your array or handle your exceptions however you would like. Once you have your array of values, it is easy to add them back to the combo boxes. I would recommend that you have the combo boxes in an array or something similar, so you can associate the index of your string array to the index of the combo box. Without something like this, it would be difficult to determine which string goes where. In the loading code I am writing below, I am assuming your combo boxes are in a list, so the first string in the "values" list goes to the first combo box and the n-th string goes to the n-th combo box.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfComboBoxes; i++) {
    comboBoxes.get(i).setSelectedItem(values.get(i));
}
```

The `.setSelectedItem` sets the focus of the combo box to the value passed into it, and does nothing if the value passed into it is not in the combo box.

I would recommend looking at the javadoc in order to understand a bit more behind what is happening.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html